# Parametric Plot - Opacity Changing Along Line

Tags: plotting, manipulate, parametric-functions

How would one have the trajectory in a parametric plot go from a higher to lower opacity? Suppose the following code for example:

```
Manipulate[ParametricPlot[{Cos[f1 t], Sin[f1 t]},
  {t, 0, 4 π}, PlotRange -> 2, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"],
 {{f1, -0.3, "Frequency 1"}, -2 π, 2 π}]
```

This would show a circle. The goal is to show the line as a 'faded track' to represent the time progression, as opposed to a boring ol' solid line. I tried adding `Opacity[t/(4 π)]` to the plot options, which unsurprisingly failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Manipulate[ParametricPlot[{Cos[f1 t], Sin[f1 t]}, {t, 0, 4 Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> Thickness[.01], 
  ColorFunction -> (Opacity[1 - #3/ 4 / Pi, Red] &), 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotRange -> 2, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], 
 {{f1, -0.3, "Frequency 1"}, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Or use

```
 ColorFunction -> (Opacity[#3/ 4/Pi, Red] &)
```

to get

[image]

Comment: What does ```Opacity[1 - #3/ 4 / Pi, Red] &``` mean? I don't understand the argument nor the ampersand

Comment: @CaptainMorgan See [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) and [`ColorFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html) in the documentation.

Comment: @CaptainMorgan, for `ParametricPlot` that produces a curve (two argument form: ParametricPlot[{$f_x$, $f_y$}, {$t$ ,$t_{min} , t_{max}$}] ) the settings for option `ColorFunction` can be _functions_ that take three  arguments (`x`, `y` and `t`).  The function `Opacity[1 - #3/ 4 / Pi, Red] &` is the same as `Function[{x,y, t}, Opacity[t/4/Pi, Red]]`.

Comment: @kglr, so the ```#3``` is effectively ```t```. Where is this referenced from? Would ```#2``` be ```y``` such that the trajectory would instead change opacity based on height? Also, I see that in the documentation that ```&``` points to the function argument (I think?) I don't understand its role though here. Nothing follows it.

Comment: @CaptainMorgan, you are right, `#n` refers to the $n$th argument. See [Slot (#)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Slot.html)  in the documentation.  you can define a function in a number of ways: For example, `f1 = Function[{x, y, z}, x + 2 y + 3 z];f2 = (# + 2 #2 + 3 #3) &;
f3[x_, y_, z_] := x + 2 y + 3 z` are alternative ways of defining the same function, and `f1[a, b, c]`,`f2[a, b, c]` and `f3[a, b, c]` all give `a + 2 b + 3 c`.

Comment: @kglr, ah I think I see it now. Thank you